# Where is the Segfault Error in this c++ code?

Tags: c++, c++11

So after I included the function `parse_input` I always get a segfault error. I have tried many things but none work. My current code is:

test.cpp

```c
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Client.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

using namespace ::testing;

TEST(ClientInputParse, RegularWeekdays) {
    std::vector<Days> days = {Days::Mon, Days::Tues, Days::Wed};
    auto client = Client();
    client.parse_input("Regular: 16Mar2009(mon), 17Mar2009(tues), 18Mar2009(wed)");
    Client expected(ClientType::Regular, days);

    ASSERT_EQ(client, expected);
}
```

header:

```c
#ifndef Client_h
#define Client_h

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <functional>

enum ClientType {
    Regular,
    Rewards,
};

enum Days {
    Mon = 0,
    Tues = 1,
    Wed = 2,
    Thur = 3,
    Fri = 4,
    Sat = 5,
    Sun = 6,
};

class UnknownDayOfTheWeek
{
public:
    UnknownDayOfTheWeek(){};
};

class UnknownClient
{
public:
    UnknownClient(){};
};


struct Client {
    std::vector<Days> days_;
    ClientType type_;
    
    public: 
        Client(ClientType client_type, std::vector<Days> days) : days_(days), type_(client_type) {};
        Client() {};

        void parse_input(const std::string input);
};

bool operator==(const Client& lhs, const Client& rhs);

#endif
```

impl:

```c
#include "Client.h"

ClientType parse_client_type(const std::string& client_type_input);
std::vector<Days> parse_client_days(const std::string& client_days_input);

void Client::parse_input(const std::string input) {
    std::string client_type_input = input.substr(0, input.find(":"));
    std::string client_days_input = input.substr(input.find(":"));

    ClientType client_type = parse_client_type(client_type_input);
    std::vector<Days> days = parse_client_days(client_days_input);
    type_ = client_type;
    days_ = days;
}

ClientType parse_client_type(const std::string& client_type_input) {
    if (client_type_input == "Regular") {
        return ClientType::Regular;
    } else if (client_type_input == "Rewards") {
        return ClientType::Rewards;
    } else {
        throw UnknownClient();
    }
}

std::vector<Days> parse_client_days(const std::string& client_days_input) {
    std::vector<Days> days;
    std::vector<std::string> days_tokens;  
    std::stringstream ss(client_days_input);

    std::string intermediate;
    
    while(getline(ss, intermediate, ','))
    {
        days_tokens.push_back(intermediate);
    }

    std::transform(days_tokens.begin(), days_tokens.end(), days.begin(), [](std::string token) { 
        if (token.find("mon") != std::string::npos) {
            return Days::Mon;
        } else if (token.find("tues") != std::string::npos) {
            return Days::Tues;
        } else if (token.find("wed") != std::string::npos) {
            return Days::Tues;
        } else if (token.find("thur") != std::string::npos) {
            return Days::Tues;
        } else if (token.find("fri") != std::string::npos) {
            return Days::Tues;
        } else if (token.find("sat") != std::string::npos) {
            return Days::Tues;
        } else if (token.find("sun") != std::string::npos) {
            return Days::Tues;
        }

        throw UnknownDayOfTheWeek();
    });

    return days;
}

bool operator==(const Client& lhs, const Client& rhs) {
    return lhs.type_ == rhs.type_ && (lhs.days_.size() == rhs.days_.size() &&
            std::equal(lhs.days_.begin(), lhs.days_.end(), rhs.days_.begin()));
}
```

Terminal output:

```
[----------] 1 test from ClientInputParse
[ RUN      ] ClientInputParse.RegularWeekdays
zsh: segmentation fault  ./test
```

Comment: "*I always get a segfault error*" - have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see exactly where it is going wrong?  Also, do you realize that your `parse_input()` is creating a new `Client` object instead of modifying the `Client` object it is called on?

Comment: Why do you tag C if you have C++ code?  Are you mixing languages?  Mixing languages is not recommended, as it makes your program more complex and prone to issues.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Just fixed it, it was something I tried and pasted incorrectly here.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think it was a mistag when tagging c++11

Comment: Only 20 more years until `c++11` becomes the new `turboc++` tag.

Answer (score 1):

In `parse_client_days()`, your use of `std::transform()` is trying to modify an *empty* vector `days`. When `transform()` tries to write to the element referred to by the `days` iterator, it crashes since there is no valid element to write to.

You need to either:

1. make the size of `days` match the size of `day_tokens` before calling `std::transform()`:

```cpp
days.resize(days_tokens.size()); // <-- add this
std::transform(days_tokens.begin(), days_tokens.end(), days.begin(), ...);
```

2. use [`std::back_inserter()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) for the output iterator:

```cpp
std::transform(days_tokens.begin(), days_tokens.end(), std::back_inserter(days), ...);
```